# ASP.NET MVC4 and MySQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting a project with asp.net mvc4 (vb) and I would use mysql as databse. I've read that i can also use EF but at the moment I do not care.

How can I interface mvc4 asp.net to mysql? I can not find nullad interesting in the network.

Comment: MySQL provides a driver for .NET.  Have you tried using it?

Comment: I'm sorry Anderson, I found this question but I do not know why I thought it was for MVC2

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) backed by MySQL. I wouldn't say the usage is that similar to EF, but they're both ORMs and MVC4 is designed to be pluggable with respect to models.

I have however downvoted your question as you obviously didn't search to see whether the question had been answered before.